# Object is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, commonjs

I'm trying to create an object in javavscript and then initializing it in another file. I don't seem to understand the problem even though everything looks correct to me. Below is my code

```
    class Account {
       constructor(account_id, official_name, name, subtype, type, balances) {
    this.account_id = account_id;
    this.official_name = official_name;
    this.name = name;
    this.subtype = subtype;
    this.type = type;
    this.balances = balances;
  }
}
module.exports = Account;
```

and this is how I'm creating it:

```
 const { Account } = require('../../model/account');
const {
      account_id, name, official_name, subtype, type, balances
    } = accounts[key];
    const account = new Account(account_id, official_name, name, subtype, type, balances);
```

and the error:

```
TypeError: Account is not a constructor
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're using `module.exports` so try `const Account = require('../../model/account');`

Comment: `module.exports = Account;` means that your import should be `const Account = require(...)`, not `const { Account } = require(...)` If you want to export `Account` by name, use `exports.Account = Account` instead.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks guys, now i understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

So as Patrick Roberts explained in the comments, either

```
module.exports.Account = Account
```

```
const { Account } = require('../../model/account')
```

or

```
module.exports = Account
```

```
const Account = require('../../model/account')
```